# iCloud account other domains

Tags: icloud, apple-mail

I am developing a web application with go as backend. It has a functionality that uses **github.com/emersion/go-imap/v2** imap client to login. In that, I am not able to login to icloud account of other domains (doesnt end with icloud.com) with the app password. For instance, I have a gmail account abc@gmail.com I have created an Apple ID for the same account. And I try to login to that icloud account using app password using the imap client. But getting **Authentication failed** error. But I am able to login to accounts that end with icloud.com using the imap client. Is there any way I could login to icloud accounts that have different domains?

Thanks in Advance